# Silverlight displays timeout error when calling WCF function

Tags: wcf, silverlight, timeout

I'm using VS2010, C# to develop a Silverlight 4 web application, this app reads emails using a WCF. Of course I've created a Silverlight User Control which interacts with WCF, and use this user control in my main Silverlight application.

Sometimes I get following error message when trying to read my inbox, it seems that a timeout should be increased, is it possible to disable this timeout? Since it may take a too long time to read some emails and having a timeout will disturb the performance. How can I solve this problem:

```
The HTTP request to 'http://localhost:1968/EmailWCF.svc' has exceeded the allotted timeout. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
```

of course I get the same error when I upload my service and app to remote server

Comment: If you *expect* slow performance on the server, you should really change you programming pattern to use a background task/thread on the server and poll for the results.

Comment: I changed my timeouts and it works now, of course it is a bit slower than what I expect, how can I improve its performance?

Comment: Same comment as before... If you want a faster client, change the way you cache your emails. e.g. get the server to do the slow work in the background and cache it in a server database